# Entity Framework - Is there a way to reorder properties in the EDMX designer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework's model designer to design the model for a new project.

Adding properties is relatively easy, however they're always appended to the entity.

Is there a way to reorder the properties once they've been added?  This is quite annoying!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In VS2012 it's much easier: just press <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> with the property selected.

Comment: Sounds great Dave, but it doesn't work for me in the EDMX designer. Can you confirm the version you're using and how you do this exactly? I'm using VS2010 and EntityFramework v4.3.1.0.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm using 2012 RC so that feature may be new. I thought I had done that before but it's too late to test as I've restaged my PC (since VS uninstall so badly sux) and I only wanted one VS version.

Comment: Well, good to know that this is supported in the newer VS. Looking forward to trying it out, although uninstalling an earlier 2012 beta destroyed my 2010 installation so I'm waiting for the RTM now.

Comment: Just tested this in VS2012 with EF v4.3.1.0 and it doesn't work, so this must be a new feature of EF 5.0.

Comment: Confirmed that it -is- working with VS 2012 Pro v4.5.50709, targeting .NET 4.5 and EF5. :) Happy day.

Comment: No luck in VS2013, EF6.0

Comment: VS2013 has the following shortcuts as well (commands are available via the pop-up menu "Move Properties" either, when you click on the property name in the entity diagram): To Top - Alt + Home; To Bottom - Alt + End; Up: Alt + Up Arrow; Down: Alt + Down Arrow; Up 5: Alt + PgUp Arrow; Down 5: Alt + PgDn

Answer (score 24):

I assume by "reorder the properties" you mean the order that the properties are show up in the EDM designer and if that's what you mean then Yes, there is:

1. Right Click on your edmx file in solution explorer and choose "Open With..."

2. Select the 2nd item: Automatic Editor Selector(XML) and click OK.

3. Click on Yes where it ask if you want to close the edmx file.

4. Now you should see the XML file that is being created behind the scene.

5. Find your EntityType node that you need to reorder its properties: it is in the CSDL content like: < EntityType Name="yourEntityName">. Underneath there are a whole bunch of property nodes: < Property Type="" Name=""...
Change the order of the scalar properties, save and double click on the edmx file to open it in designer mode again... You'll see that the order has been changed!

Comment: Thanks, but wow.  I was hoping for drag-and-drop or a keyboard shortcut.  Even just being able to reorder alphabetically would have been welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Download https://github.com/timabell/ef-edmx-sorter/releases/latest, extract it, and run it against your .edmx file. It will read the storage model (which will match your database field order) and use that to re-order the properties in the conceptual model.

```
EfEdmxSorter.exe -i path/to/your.emdx
```